# How to fetch unique id to delete the data in React Native Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store my data. Now i want to delete the data under Shops Section but i am not understanding that how to fetch the Unique id to delete the data here is the screen shot.

```
Shops
  4azTPmwIpbY9vfwf9CxKMMK74kI2
    -LuTY5RZLYFqeY5iPjfR
    -LxMsiVGtW5xgw4XsKQi
      description: "demo"
      image_url_banner: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2Q..."
      image_url_logo: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAAMgCAIAAAC8ggxVAAA..."
      name: "demo"
      tagline: "demo shop here"
```

Here is my code i am not able to get id of any shop

```
deleteItem=()=>{

  let shopRef = firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
let shopId = shopRef.key;
Alert.alert("id" , shopId)
  var updates = {};
    updates["/Shops/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + shopId] = null;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .update(updates);
}
```

please suggest some code

Comment: What does the `Alert.alert("id" , shopId)` show?

Comment: My suspicion is that you're missing a `/` between the `UID` and `shopId`. So: `updates["/Shops/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + "/" + shopId] = null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
  let shopRef = firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
shopRef.on("value",(snapshot) => {
 snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
  var id = childSnapshot.key;
  firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child(id).remove();
 });
});
```

First attach a listener, then iterate inside the key and retrieve it using the key property.

Check here for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: please suggest that how to delete a specific shop

Comment: to delete call the method `remove()` on the location

Comment: can i delete inside that foreach() ??

Comment: yes but u need to use a query to retrieve the correct id `shopRef.orderByChild("description").equalTo("demo").on("value",(snapshot) => {`

Comment: but inside foreach() it will remove all the shops how can i delete a specific one which  i want to delete.I am getting all the shops ids correctly from your above suggetion

Comment: you need to use a query to get the correct id `shopRef.orderByChild("description").equalTo("demo").on("value",(snapshot) => {`